# How to compare timestamp by hours using moment

Tags: javascript, react-native, jestjs, momentjs

I have the following function which is responsible for returning a boolean value depending on whether a cutoff period is active or not, based on a Unix timestamp returned by a Server.

Here is the function:

```
 export const isCutOffTimePeriod = function (currentDateTime) {
  const format = 'HH:mm a'
  const currentTime = moment(currentDateTime).utcOffset(-300)
  const openingTime = moment('8:00 am', format)
  const closingTime = moment('2:30 pm', format)


  return !currentTime.isBetween(openingTime, closingTime)
}
```

I am writing a test in Jest for this function:

```
 it('Should allow a transfer between 8:30am and 2:30pm ', () => {
  const currentDateTime = mockData.dateTime.nineAm // 1527862941959 - Friday,June 1, 2018 9:22:21.959 AM GMT-05:00
  expect(Utils.isCutOffTimePeriod(currentDateTime)).toEqual(false)
})
```

The test fails even tho based on the output all the times are correctly being stored in the moment object based on logs, how do I compare a unix timestamp to other times based solely on the hours and minutes?

Comment: By [jest] tag you mean the js testing framework right ? then the correct tag is [jestjs]. [jest] tag is for Java HTTP Rest client for ElasticSearch.

Comment: works fine, as 9.20am is between 8.30am and 2.30pm

Comment: https://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/rbJQbm

Comment: My test is failing though since the function is returning true

Comment: The UTC offset in your function is `-300`. In your test, you are using a `-500` offset.

Comment: Are you tying to check that the timestamp, when converted to localtime, is between 8:30am and 2:30pm?

Comment: @Richard how do I set the offset for the test?

Comment: Yes that's what I am trying to do @SalmanA

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.startOf('minute')` and `.endOf('minute')`. Like this:

And you can just pass a Unix timestamp directly to Moment to create a object that reflects that timestamp. Here:

```js
function test(unixTimestampForComparasion) {
  const format = 'HH:mm a';
  var currentDateTime = moment(unixTimestampForComparasion);
  const openingTime = moment('8:00 am', format).startOf('minute');
  const closingTime = moment('2:30 pm', format).endOf('minute');
  
  return !currentDateTime.isBetween(openingTime, closingTime)
}

console.log(test(moment("08:00:20 am", 'HH:mm:ss a').valueOf()));
console.log(test(moment("2:30:20 pm", 'HH:mm:ss a').valueOf()));
console.log(test(moment("2:31:00 pm", 'HH:mm:ss a').valueOf()));

var testTimeAsUnixTimestamp = moment("2019-01-01 2:31:00 pm", 'HH:mm:ss a').valueOf();
console.log(testTimeAsUnixTimestamp);
console.log(test(testTimeAsUnixTimestamp));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment-with-locales.js"></script>
```

Please understand that you are inverting the inBetween test. So the results can be a bit confusing. But they are correct.

Also I removed the locale offset line so the example became more clear. Just include it again ASA you get it to work.

Comment: and can this method be applied to unix timestamps ? the `currentDateTime` is going to be something like `1527862941959`

Comment: See my edit. It would be better if you included this in the initial question so it's easier for other users to understand.

Comment: It was included in the initial question, and is in fact the title of the question, so given that knowledge how would the answer look?

Comment: It will simply fail when the timestamp is specified.

Comment: Yes... reread it and seen you're correct. Edited the answer. :)